# Update foreign key with other field PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php page where I can Create, Update and see some users and other page where I can see the user's(`colaboradores's table`) items(`ativos's table`) and they are linked with an FK(`id_colaborador`).
On the `ativos` create page, I manage to input all the data and instead of input the FK itselv (`id_colaborador`) the user can input the NAME of the user (`colaboradores.nome`).
The point is, I want to do the same thing on the UPDATE.PHP page, but I just can't figure it out how to input the `colaboradores.nome` on the `id.colaborador (FK)` field instead of it...
Sorry if I couldn't explain myself clearly.
Here's the `$sql` var with the query for `create.php`:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ativos (ativo,comentario,data_aquisicao,localizacao,fabricante,modelo,imei,
            numero_serie,ativo_sap,evento,data_evento,id_colaborador) 
            SELECT ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, id_colaborador 
            FROM colaboradores 
            WHERE nome = ?";
```

And here's the `$sql` var with the query for `update.php`:

```
 $sql = "UPDATE ativos  SET ativo = ?, comentario = ?, data_aquisicao = ?, localizacao = ?, fabricante = ?, modelo = ?, imei = ?, 
        numero_serie = ?, ativo_sap = ?, anexo_a = ?, evento = ?, data_evento = ?, id_colaborador = ? WHERE id_ativo = ?";
```

Thank you for you time!
**Update:**
I mean, is it possible to get the `update` code similiar to the `create` code?
Update must `select` the `colaboradores.nome` to replace `id.colaborador (FK)` and keep the `WHERE id_ativo = ?` something like that i gues...

```
$sql = "UPDATE ativos  SET ativo = ?, comentario = ?, data_aquisicao = ?, localizacao = ?, fabricante = ?, modelo = ?, imei = ?, 
        numero_serie = ?, ativo_sap = ?, anexo_a = ?, evento = ?, data_evento = ? SELECT id_colaborador FROM colaboradores 
        WHERE nome = ? AND WHERE id_ativo = ?";
```

Comment: Why would you at all want to update that ID? Can't you just leave it out? It's already there, right?

Comment: Furthermore, are you getting any errors? Or is it just not working? If you are getting errors, please include them in your question :).

Comment: if you update the related object (ativo's) you don't have to set the ID + Name of colaboradores table again just leave it out.

Comment: @minitauros That ID it's the user's ID, I want to update that field because the item's user can be switched (let's say that an Iphone is with Mike, Mike(`id=1`) leaves and that Iphone goes to Joe(`id=2`))

Comment: Im not getting any more errors

Comment: I've updated the question!

Comment: Have you tried executing the query manually? With manually entered values? See what happens? Maybe the query is not the error, but the values inserted.

Comment: I mean, is it possible to get the `update` code similiar to the `create` code?
Update must select the `colaboradores.nome` to replace `id.colaborador (FK)` and keep the `WHERE id_ativo = ?`

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate a list with PHP (e.g. dropdown) containing name as label and id as value.
So users will be able to select in a list of name. When selection is made, you have to use the value (id).

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <select name="Users">
        <option value="1">Paul</option>
        <option value="2">Pierre</option>
        <option value="5">Marco</option>
        <option value="8">Jean</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get Selected Values" />
</form>
```

Then retreive id with PHP

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $selected_val = $_POST['Users'];  // Storing Selected Value In Variable
        echo "You have selected :" .$selected_val;  // Displaying Selected Value
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Nicolas, but I'll have more than 300 users.. I can't have a dropdown like that :/
I was thinking on an Autocomplete as I have on create.php, but for some reason it won't work on update.php :/ I was thinking if I can have two `WHERE` clauses but idk

Comment: @CarlosSantiago an autocomplete can be made to work to select the ID, you just gotta set it up properly. We don't know what you did wrong, but maybe you should edit the question to include that, if that's now your issue. P.S. Inputting the name directly is no good, because it's not unique - eventually you'll have two users called Mike. You can get the user to _select_ by name, but what you need to send to the server is the resulting ID.

Comment: @CarlosSantiago ATM most of dropdown are implemented with search. So if you input "Mi" when dropdown has focus, the list will move to the first input matching "Mi"

Comment: @Nicolas true but it's really basic (only search from the start of the string), is not user-friendly (feature is hidden and also doesn't show you what's going on when you type) and most people probably don't even know about it. Plus 300 is still an unwieldy list in any case - it might drop off the bottom of the screen depending on the page design. An autocomplete would a much nicer solution.

Comment: I mean, is it possible to get the `update` code similiar to the `create` code?
Update must select the `colaboradores.nome` to replace `id.colaborador (FK)` and keep the `WHERE id_ativo = ?`